# Are some std classes in C++ used in real life applications?

Tags: c++, production-environment, production

I have a question, in real applications like: companies, software development, etc... Do they use some `std` classes(or containers, I'm not sure about the correct name) such as `std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::string` in the code? Or do they implement new ones?

Comment: Of course, why are you doubting? What do you think is wrong with the standard library?

Comment: I think because my first laguage was Python. I moved to c++ which is morer "advanced", so I thought maybe companies would prefer to write some similar code by themselves

Comment: Spend dollars on your own programmer's when you can get high quality library code for free?

Comment: Of course companies in specialized areas will spend time developing their own in house library code for a variety of purposes. But there are huge benefits (not only cost) in using standardized libraries for most purposes.

Comment: @LucasSaito when you used Python, did you use the standard library, or did you implement all functionality it offers yourself?

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @LucasSaito You'd probably be prone to be fired, if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the platform that your building to. If its for embedded applications, you might use a custom implementation to fit that platform and to get better performance.

If its for a desktop application, you'll most likely use the provided STL containers (why reinvent the wheel?).

Or else there could be scenarios like the Unreal Engine, where the STL wasn't a go-to option when its first built (and other reasons like code reflection).

The STL containers might not be the *best and most efficient* implementation
because its made to work on many cases but its more or less feature complete; it has everything which a coder would need when developing something using that container. With that said, performance differences are in the range of nanoseconds, which in modern devices makes unnoticeable differences. The performance gets unnoticeable even further when your talking about cross-platform compatibility, documentation and the ease of development.

Comment: _"If its for embedded applications, you might use a custom implementation to fit that platform and to get better performance."_ When I was working with embedded c++ software (for many years in my career), it was an absolute **must** requirement, that if you implement your custom containers, or other replacements for standard classes (like e.g. threads, standard I/O via UART etc.), that these are designed to be compatible with the c++ standard library (algorithms, iterators, etc.).